# How to upgrade Solaris-11 package?

Tags: solaris

I am installing OVM Server on Sparc and during installation, it is failing on one package. It is not giving me a clear idea. what do I need to do to fix it?

> root@ovs-server1:# ./install

```
Oracle VM Agent Release 3.4.6 Installer

- Installing Packages

Updating package cache                           1/1
Creating Plan (Solver setup): -
pkg install: No matching version of ovm/ovs-agent can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://ovm/ovm/ovs-agent@3.4.6-3.4.6.0.0.2232
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency system/io/test-drivers can be installed
    ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/system/io/test-drivers@11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0
    Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation@11.4-11.4.11.0.1.4.0
    ----------------------------------------

There was an error during the installation. The Oracle VM Agent
might not be fully installed or configured.

root@ovs-server1:#
root@ovs-server1:/# pkg list -af system/io/test-drivers
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
system/io/test-drivers (solaris)                  11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0       ---
root@ovs-server1:/# pkg list -af osnet-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation (solaris) 11.4-11.4.11.0.1.4.0       i--
consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation (solaris) 11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0       ---
root@ovs-server1:/#
root@ovs-server1:/# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris                     origin   online F file:///repo/
root@ovs-server1:/# df -h /repo
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/repo              25G    10G        15G    41%    /repo
root@ovs-server1:/# ls -ltr /repo
total 34
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         347 Aug 16  2018 pkg5.repository
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         573 Aug 16  2018 readme.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        5949 Aug 16  2018 README-repo-iso.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        1626 Aug 16  2018 NOTICES
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        3440 Aug 16  2018 COPYRIGHT
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root           3 Feb 27 00:53 publisher
root@ovs-server1:/#
root@ovs-server1:/# pkg list -af entire
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
entire                                            11.4-11.4.11.0.1.4.0       i--
entire                                            11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0       ---
root@ovs-server1:/# pkg update -nv
No updates available for this image.
root@ovs-server1:/# pfexec pkg update -nv entire@11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0
Creating Plan (Solver setup): /
pkg update: Package 'library/python/pillow-34' must be uninstalled or upgraded if the requested operation is to be performed.
  Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/pillow-34@5.1.0-11.4.9.0.1.5.0
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency image/library/openjpeg2@2.3.0-11.4.4.0.1.4.0 can be installed
    ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/image/library/openjpeg2@2.3.1-11.4.11.0.1.2.0
    Reason:  Excluded by proposed incorporation 'consolidation/userland/userland-incorporation'
    ----------------------------------------
```

How can I fix/upgrade it?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `Package 'library/python/pillow-34' must be uninstalled or upgraded if the requested operation is to be performed.`

Comment: Looks like the OVM software depends on a (very) old version of `pkg://solaris/system/io/test-drivers`. Did you download the latest available OVM version?

Comment: Besides, the version of Solaris you're running is from July 2019, probably time to update...

Answer (score 0):

This looks as though something is up with your Solaris repo.

You have SRU11 installed and the installer is trying to install the corresponding system/io/test-drivers package but that's failing.

I'd expect 'pkg list -af system/io/test-drivers' to show the SRU11 version of the package if it was available. But it doesn't.

This can happen if the system was updated to SRU11, the system/io/test-drivers was never installed, and then someone unset the publisher for example.

You need to check that you have the solaris publisher pointed to the support repo from Oracle or an internal copy that has all the content for SRU11.